# How to change v-switch color when in toggle-off state

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been trying to change the color of the v-switch when it is in a toggle off state,
I wanted to change the color from default grey to green but nothing seemed to have worked

I have tried  changing style using v-input--switch__thumb theme--light class name but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
.v-input--switch:not(.v-input--switch--flat):not(.v-input--switch--inset) .v-input--switch__thumb {
  color: red
}

.theme--light.v-input--switch .v-input--switch__track {
  color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override styles globally:

```
.theme--light.v-input--switch .v-input--switch__track {
  color: green !important;
}

.theme--light.v-input--switch.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--is-dirty) .v-input--switch__track {
  color: green !important;
}
```